# My inline list is breaking if I put something in it what do i do?

Tags: html, css

If i move my mouse over any of the li's it is going out of place. What do i do to fix it?

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/z970pg6n/

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.pictures li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  clear: both;
}

ul li p {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

ul li:hover p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pictures">
  <li>
    <p>Sokina Jue</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Sokina Jue</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Sokina Jue</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Sokina Jue</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Simply using flex; [https://jsfiddle.net/f6s9e5p4/](https://jsfiddle.net/f6s9e5p4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weird effect is caused by changing the `display` property from `block` to `inline-block` on hover. If you want the content to be shown on hover, but hidden by default,  I would suggest using the property `visibility` instead of `display`.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.pictures li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  clear: both;
}

ul li p {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

ul li:hover p {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pictures">
  <li>
    <p>Sokina Jue</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Sokina Jue</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Sokina Jue</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Sokina Jue</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```